# Does a negative cross correlation show high or low similarity?

Tags: image, image-processing, processing, correlation, cross-correlation

I am programming some image processing techniques which requires comparing the similarity of two sub images. I'm using a the normalised cross correlation metric which returns a value between -1 and +1. Should I be taking the absolute value of this as my similarity measure or does negative cross correlation imply a poor similarity?

Comment: You should only consider the positive score as similar - assume anything negative means no correlation (because this is negative correlation).

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was hoping to hear!

Answer (score 5):

Negative and positive correlation is meaningful and all depends on your application. Let me to make it more clear. Suppose you have three datasets (e.g. A : Age, B : Hair and C : Height). Suppose that the correlation between A and C is positive (0.98), so it mean that by increasing the age, it is expected to be taller). However, we you calculate the correlation between A and B, you find that it is negative! What does it mean? It means by increasing age, you expect to have less hair! So, as you can see, positive correlation means a parallel increasing/decreasing in both dataset, while negative correlation means having two opposite trend which can be meaningful, because base on the negative correlation you can expect to have more hair when you are kid!

Comment: Good answer and application, but the OP wanted to know how it applies to digital image processing techniques.  Still, a very good answer from a statistics point of view!

Comment: Isn't standard correlation (e.g. Pearson) different to cross correlation?

Answer (score 3):

-1 is a sign of correlation, too. Only values around 0 are an indication that there is no correlation. Near +1 means, that the image is very similar to the other one. Near -1 means, that it's likely that one image is a negative and should be inverted, so the images are similar and get a correlation near +1.

Comment: Using negative correlation also depends on the application.  For example, if you wanted to perform template matching, then negative correlation isn't useful because it would still be considered dissimilar.  However, if you wanted to use the score for retrieval purposes, then high negative correlation is useful because you would want to find that particular shape or object regardless of its orientation.  As such, you'll need to think about what you are using correlation for before deciding if negative correlation is useful.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC) used as similarity function has different properties than the correlation. Positive large values implies high similarity, while negative large values implies low similarity.

If your input matrices have only positive values, you cannot have negative NCC values. However, if your implementation of the NCC removes first the intensity mean value of the images, your images will have positive and negative NCC values. Hence, you can have negative NCC values, like [normxcorr2](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html)

[image]

**TL;DR**

First, you are trying to do image registration (template matching), i.e. transform an image to fit the coordinate system of the template image. In order to do that, you need to use a *similarity function* (or dissimilarity function) to estimate the needed transformation.

I assume that:

- You only apply *linear transformations*. Hence, it is needed to
  estimate the spatial orthogonal misalignment between the two images,
  offset in the x- and y-axis
- Both images have the same modality,
  *single modality*, where both template and image were captured by the same device/configuration.

Hence, the use of the normalized cross-correlation seems like a good option. If the previous assumptions don't apply, please use other similarity function

The Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC) is an intensity-based similarity function. Hence, it measures how similar two images are based only on the pixel intensity. Basically, the image is spatially shifted over the template. For each shift, it is added the pixel by pixel multiplication at each overlapping position.

Therefore, for maximum alignment, you need to shift the image to the position that maximise the similarity between the two images, i.e. largest NCC

See also: [image registering](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are right in saying that "the Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC) used as similarity function has different properties than the correlation. Positive large values implies high similarity, while negative large values implies low similarity."

1. Correlation in images is no different than the other types of non-image correlations.
2. In NCC a correlation value of +1 indicates two images are identical pixel-by-pixel. A correlation value of 0 indicates no similarity. However a correlation value of -1 does not imply no similarity. It also means maximum similarity,  but in the opposite sense. The image pixels in the normalized domain can take values in the range [0 1]. If you take one of the images, subtract all pixel values from 1 (1-(pixel_value)), you create an inverted image, where bright spots become dark and dark spots become light.  If correlation with the original image produced a correlation value of 1 (100% similarity), the correlation with the inverted image produces an correlation value of -1.